# Black screen, X cursor after boot

Tags: boot, 13.10

Whenever I boot to Ubuntu 13.10, it goes to a black screen with my cursor that looks like an a X. There is also a `System program problem detected` message box in my used theme, and I can switch to console logins fine. I have already tried booting with nomodegui or whatever that is, and it doesn't solve the problem.

[image]